# Running a Java Application from the Windows Context Menu

Tags: java, windows, contextmenu

I would like to create a Java application that can be opened from the context menu of any given file or directory on the computer. I know how to add my program to the registry so that it appears when right-clicking on a file, but how can I receive the location of the directory/file from which my program was run in order to work with it inside the application?

Is there a way that I can receive it as an argument in the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your jar to exe file.
then you add to registry and whatever..
if you set whenever you open with right click on file **( you must set the file association, that is your application. Ex: Right click on your targeted file select *open with* and select your application  )** your application main function receive the path in **args[0].** that's all...

Comment: But it will be limited to windows platform only, since java is designed for cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Add the context menu. Tell it to run CMD. Tell CMD to run the jar (and then close).

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ * \shell\ClickMe\Command
default="cmd \\c java c:\myJar.jar \"%1\""
```